# leafletjs tile pixel coordinate

Tags: d3.js, maps, leaflet

I am experimenting with leafletjs and wanted to get the pixel coordinate of the tile? Pixel coordinate as in left/top or x/y centroid of the tile element.
I have extended a gridlayer and trying to get tile coordinate in the createTile method.

So basically I want to get the pixel coordinates of every tile generated by the gridlayer.

Please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply multiply the tile's X and Y coordinates (from the `coords` argument that the `createTile` callback method receives) by the tile size. That's the pixel coordinate for the top-left corner.

Please note that these coordinates are pixel coordinates from the origin of coordinates of the map's CRS, and the pixel coordinates are relative to the grid's zoom level. A good explanation of Leaflet's concept of CRS origin of coordinates is at http://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html